# Combine two SQL Server table results to pull latest data where exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, isnull

I have two tables a main table and a work in progress table.  Any inserts/updates are inserted into the WIP table while the record is being manipulated, this allows for validation checks and the like.  I want to create a view that combines the two tables showing the WIP table data whenever it exists and the main table data when there is no WIP data.

I have figured out a way to do this but it seems that it's not the most elegant solution.  I would like to know if there are other ideas or better solutions?

Example illustrating the situation:

```
select mt.id, wt.id wip_id, isnull(wt.name,mt.name) name, 
       isnull(wt.address, mt.address) address
from main_table mt full outer join
       wip_table wt on mt.id = wt.orig_id;
```

So that will pull results from the WIP table when they exist, if they dont it will pull results from the main table.  This was a simple example but the tables could have many rows.

Comment: much better if you can include the schema :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want data either from one table or the other:

```
select top 1 *
from
(
select 1 as prio, wt.name, wt.address, .... from wip_table wt where ...
union
select 2 as prio, mt.name, mt.address, .... from main_table mt where ...
order by prio
) x
```

otherwise, like you have done (checking individual columns), but maybe using a left outer join rather than a full one:

```
select 
  mt.id
  , wt.id wip_id
  , isnull(wt.name,mt.name) name
  , isnull(wt.address, mt.address) address
from main_table mt left outer join wip_table wt 
  on mt.id = wt.orig_id;
```

Comment: Yes, i need the full outer just because in the case of a new insert the "orig_id" field in the WIP table is null until it gets actually inserted into the main table when the record is deleted from the WIP table.  On the records getting updated the orig_id is populated with the ID (PK) from the main table so if an item is getting updated i want to see that WIP value that is about to be applied.

Comment: You should use "union all" instead of "union", unless you explicitly want to remove duplicates.

Comment: @Gordon: I won't have dups due to the prio column. But union all is better anyway as it saves a sort.